# File Handling - Reading from the beginning again

Tags: java, arrays, io

I need to create an array of objects to save the records from files. I don't know about the size of an array. For that I have to find the number of lines in a file first. Using the number of lines, size of an array can be determined. Now I need to read the file again from the beginning to store records from the file in array object. This is where I am struggling. I don't know how to implement in order to read the file again from the beginning. Please advise.

```
/**
     * Loads the game records from a text file.
     * A GameRecord array is constructed to store all the game records.
     * The size of the GameRecord array should be the same as the number of non-empty records in the text file.
     * The GameRecord array contains no null/empty entries.
     * 
     * @param reader    The java.io.Reader object that points to the text file to be read.
     * @return  A GameRecord array containing all the game records read from the text file.
     */


    public GameRecord[] loadGameRecord(java.io.Reader reader) {
        // write your code after this line
        String[] parts;
        GameRecord[] gameRecord = null;
        FileReader fileReader = (FileReader) reader;
        java.io.BufferedReader bufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(fileReader);
        try {
            int linenumber = 0;
            String sCurrentLine;
            while ((sCurrentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                linenumber++;
            }
            gameRecord = new GameRecord[linenumber]; //creating a space for total no Of lines

            //How to read the file from the beginning again, and why I am getting bufferedReader.readLine()) as null
            bufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(fileReader); 
            while ((sCurrentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                parts = sCurrentLine.split("\t");
                    gameRecord[i] = new GameRecord(parts[0], Integer.parseInt(parts[1]),Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));
            }

        }catch (IOException exe){
            System.err.println("IOException: " + exe.getMessage());
            exe.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                if (bufferedReader!=null)
                    bufferedReader.close();
                if (fileReader!=null)
                    fileReader.close();
            }catch(IOException exe) {
                System.err.println("IOException: " + exe.getMessage());
            }           
        }
        return gameRecord; 
    }
```

Note: I will get the reference to a file as an argument. Reader class has been used. Can I use this reference for FileInputStream?

Comment: FileInputStream derived from Reader class? Reference to the file will be sent in an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current approach is very limiting because you are using an array which by definition has to be defined to have a fixed size.  A better approach would be to use an `ArrayList` of `GameRecord` objects.  With this approach, you can simply make one single pass through the file and add elements to the `ArrayList` as necessary.

**Sample code:**

```
List<GameRecord> grList = new ArrayList<GameRecord>();
bufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(fileReader); 
while ((sCurrentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    parts = sCurrentLine.split("\t");
    GameRecord gameRecord = new GameRecord(parts[0],
                                           Integer.parseInt(parts[1]),
                                           Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));
    grList.add(gameRecord);  // add the GameRecord object to the ArrayList
                             // and let the JVM worry about sizing problems
}

// finally, convert the ArrayList to an array
GameRecord[] grArray = new String[grList.size()];
grArray = grList.toArray(grArray);
```

If you *must* reset the `BufferedReader` then have a look at [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421653/reset-buffer-with-bufferedreader-in-java) which discusses this.

Comment: Nope, I need to return an array of objects as per the question

Comment: we can convert Arraylist to array by using toArray() method. after getting array from list simply return that array.

Comment: Updated my answer to return an array.  Using an array to read the file is _not_ the best way to go here.

Comment: Yes, I implemented like this only. just wanted to know how the file can be read again using BufferedReader.

Comment: You don't need to read again if you use my solution.  You can always close underlying file and then reopen it.

Comment: Think we should remove  for (int i=0; i<parts.length; i++). The same line is stored for three times. I edited the opening post too. Thank You.

It worked, when I reopened the file.

Answer (score 0):

if you used org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils, you could employ readLines method. as long as your file never contains "Too Many" records. this method returns a List which is easy to convert to array of Strings

Comment: I can't use third party APIs

Comment: then write your own java code to read complete file into ArrayList<String> then convert ArrayList to String array. you only read file once and get array as result