# Is there a way to reset the buffer when using ReversedLinesFileReader?

Tags: java, apache

I was looking at this question  - [Reset buffer with BufferedReader in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421653/reset-buffer-with-bufferedreader-in-java) -  which says that you can reset the buffer by calling:

```
fIn.getChannel().position(0);
```

But what if we are using the Apache Commons IO [ReversedLinesFileReader](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html#close())  class? Is there a way to simulate a similar action?

Comment: Sounds like something you could suggest on their issue tracker. The internal structure seems rather complicated and you would need to hack around it with reflection.

Comment: The question you cited was very poorly expressed. You can reset the underlying *file* that way, but whatever was buffered is still buffered. You need to clarify your question similarly. Do you want to reread the entire file, or only the current buffer?

Comment: @EJP - I'd like to reread only the current buffer ,  thanks