# what is the private variable "mark" in NIO Buffer used for?

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

The part of NIO Buffer source code is as follows:

```
public abstract class Buffer {
   private int mark = -1;
   private int position = 0;
   private int limit;
   private int capacity;

   ...
}
```

I want to know what is the **mark** exactly used for. There is no comment related to that in the JDK source code.

Comment: Also related http://stackoverflow.com/q/5421653/1743880

Comment: Probably it's used for [`mark()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#mark--) / `reset()`

Comment: Side note: why didn't you study the source code then? You know, the variable is private, so it can only be used in that very class; so in order to understand what the variable is used for ... you could just have searched for its usage in that class ...